# Why RxJS Subject cannot access latest data in angular component?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Here is how I am communicating between two unrelated component. Component B is trying to access myObj from component A. This is strange that `this.myObj` is not always pointing to latest data. Any reason why ?

```
component A {
      myService.pubSub.subscribe((data)=>{
        if(data.type == "getMyObj"){
            myService.pubSub.next(this.myObj);
        }
      });
}

component B {
     myService.pubSub.next({type: "getMyObj"});
}
```

Where `myService.pubSub` is just a subject in a service.

Comment: I dont understand. `myService.pubSub.subscribe((data)=>{
        if(data.type == "getMyObj"){
            myService.pubSub.next(this.myObj);
        }
      });` Are updating the same subject when you subscribe it?

Comment: It is just subject in a service. Yes I am publishing to same subject.

Comment: That will keep looping, wouldn't it? Component A will always be calling `next`

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. The issue was that, I was not unsubscribing to the subject and there were multiple subscriptions. So once I did unsubscribe, it solved the issue.

```
sub.unsubscribe();
```